# understanding compact symplectic groups

Tags: lie-groups

I am following Brian Hall's "Lie groups, Lie algebra and representations". Compact Symplectic groups (Sp(2n;R)) are intersection of skew-symmetric bilinear forms preserving Symplectic groups and inner product preserving unitary groups. I am having problem visualizing this group. my question is, why this group is important? what are the examples like for n>1?

Comment: IMHO Groups (and its subgroups) that preserve some fixed structure (such as a Riemannian metric, inner product or complex structure or ) are always useful and interesting for recognizing the underlying Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @C.F.G that somehow answers parts of my question. can you provide an possible use of this group?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you would consider an appropriate answer to this question. What do you consider the uses of $SO(n)$ or $U(n)$ to be?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  GL(n) acts as group of invertible linear transformations while SO(2) arise as group of rotation in the plane $R^{2}$, O(1,1) preserve the hyperbolas and so on...so all I am looking for is a geometrical description of the group or kind of defining property.